# How to set PseudoClass for Tab

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, pseudo-class

JavaFX's `Tab` does not descend from `Node`.

I'm trying to play around with `Tab`'s pseudo-classes, but the `pseudoClassStateChanged()` method is just missing.

There are definitely pseudo-classes for tabs, like `:disabled` when

```
tab.setDisable(true)
```

is set. There also exists a method

```
tab.getPseudoClassStates()
```

Which return's an unmodifiable set.

How do I proceed?

Comment: The `:disabled` pseudoclass is probably set for a node in the `TabPane`'s skin.